# Is there a conversion from pointer to array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

For example, for the following code, I know that `p` is a pointer, which points to the first element of the array `arr`, and I also know that the array will degenerate into an array under [certain conditions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#.E6.95.B0.E7.BB.84.E5.88.B0.E6.8C.87.E9.92.88.E8.BD.AC.E6.8D.A2:%7E:text=Array%20to%20pointer%20conversion), but why can the `[]` operation be performed on the pointer here?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int arr[10];
  arr[3] = 10;
  int* p = arr;
  cout << p[3];
  return 0;
}
```

Is there any documentation for this?
[run it online](https://godbolt.org/z/KrKd8v1K7)

Comment: Sure there is a documentation, C++ is documented by the C++ standard. Relevant quote: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sub#2.sentence-5. Important part: _"The expression `E1[E2]` is identical (by definition) to `*((E1)+(E2))`..."_.

Comment: The roots of this go at least as far back as the [B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_(programming_language)) language (1969).

Comment: And since pointer arithmetic addition is commutative, p+3 is the same as 3+p, so is dereferencing those resulting pointers. Hence, `3[p]` is not just valid, but it's the same as `p[3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the C++ 20 Standard (7.6.1.2 Subscripting)

> 1 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is
> a postfix expression. One of the expressions **shall be a glvalue of
> type “array of T” or a prvalue of type “pointer to T”** and the other
> shall be a prvalue of unscoped enumeration or integral type. The
> result is of type “T”. The type “T” shall be a completely-defined
> object type.62 The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to
> *((E1)+(E2)), except that in the case of an array operand, the result is an lvalue if that operand is an lvalue and an xvalue otherwise. The
> expression E1 is sequenced before the expression E2.

That is when an array is used in this expression `*((E1)+(E2))` then it is converted implicitly to pointer to its first element.

Comment: Looks like my search ability (and my patience) have regressed a bit, but I've decided to keep this question in order to preserve the answer =_=